# How to change Qt's default selection behavior?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am new to QGraphicsView. So for the practice purpose I was drawing some shapes like Rectangle, Ellipse, Polygon, Polyline, Text etc.
I observed here that, whenever we click on these drawn objects ( select them using mouse click )
dotted line rectangle appears around the object which indicates that, object is selected.
If I want to change that Qt's default behavior of selection, how to do that ?

> I do not want dotted rectangle around circle, when it will
> be clicked by mouse, but that dots should be around its circumference.

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include<QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;

public:
    virtual void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
};
#endif // WIDGET_H
```

widget.cpp

```
    #include "widget.h"
    #include "ui_widget.h"
    #include<QGraphicsScene>
    #include<QGraphicsView>
    #include<QGraphicsEllipseItem>
    
    Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    
        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    
        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    
        QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();
        ellipse = scene->addEllipse(2,2,80,80);
        //ellipse->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
        scene->addItem(ellipse);
    
        view->setScene(scene);
        ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(view);
    
    }
    
    Widget::~Widget()
    {
        delete ui;
    }
    
    
    void Widget :: paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
    {
            auto copied_option = *option;
            copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
            auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
            paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
            if (selected) {
                QPainterPath path;
                path.addEllipse(2,2,80,80);
                painter->save();
                painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
                painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DashLine));
                painter->drawPath(path);
                painter->restore();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there isn't any 'built in' facility to fo what you want.  In the current [code base](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#_ZN20QGraphicsEllipseItem5paintEP8QPainterPK24QStyleOptionGraphicsItemP7QWidget) you'll see...

```
void QGraphicsEllipseItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                                 QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_D(QGraphicsEllipseItem);
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    painter->setPen(d->pen);
    painter->setBrush(d->brush);
    if ((d->spanAngle != 0) && (qAbs(d->spanAngle) % (360 * 16) == 0))
        painter->drawEllipse(d->rect);
    else
        painter->drawPie(d->rect, d->startAngle, d->spanAngle);
    if (option->state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected(this, painter, option);
}
```

So the selection status indicator is drawn by `qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected` which is called directly from the `paint` method.  [`qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelected`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp.html#_ZL33qt_graphicsItem_highlightSelectedP13QGraphicsItemP8QPainterPK24QStyleOptionGraphicsItem) itself simply sets up a few basic parameters and ends by drawing the dashed rectangular border.

The obvious way to replace the default behaviour would be to subclass the `QGraphicsItem` class of interest and override the `paint` member (untested)...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsEllipseItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionGraphicsItem>

class ellipse: public QGraphicsEllipseItem {
public:
    explicit ellipse (qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height, QGraphicsItem *parent = nullptr)
        : QGraphicsEllipseItem(x, y, width, height, parent)
        {}
    virtual void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) override
    {
        auto copied_option = *option;
        copied_option.state &= ~QStyle::State_Selected;
        auto selected = option->state & QStyle::State_Selected;
        QGraphicsEllipseItem::paint(painter, &copied_option, widget);
        if (selected) {
            painter->save();
            painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
            painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DashLine));
            painter->drawPath(shape());
            painter->restore();
        }
    }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QGraphicsView view;
  QGraphicsScene scene;
  view.setScene(&scene);
  ellipse e(2, 2, 80, 80);
  e.setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
  scene.addItem(&e);
  view.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but I dont have much experience in Qt, so I could not able to call that virtual method paint(). Besides that, I could not understand, how to write selection highlight code. I understood only I should try like this. painter->setPen(Qt::DotLine);  Can you help me in this ?

Comment: @tushar I've updated the answer with a more complete example.  I'm not sure what you mean by `"I could not able to call that virtual method paint()"`: you *don't* call it, it's invoked as needed by the Qt graphics framework.

Comment: I tried but I could not succeed. I have no error but not getting dashed line around circle.  Can you help me to find where I am wrong ?  I have changed painter->drawPath(shape()); as shape() is not defined in code.

Comment: [`shape`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) *is* defined: it's a non-static virtual member of `QGraphicsItem` of which `QGraphicsEllipseItem` is a subclass.  Please add an edit to your question to show what you've tried.

Comment: I have added edit summary.

Comment: I can not see my edit summary. So I am mentioning what I have changed here. I removed shape() and added   QPainterPath path;  path.addEllipse(2,2,80,80); painter->drawPath(path);

Comment: @tushar The code in your edit bears little resemblance to the code I've shown.  You need to inherit from `QGraphicsEllipseItem` and create instances of that new class.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241822/discussion-between-tushar-and-g-m).

Comment: If my scene have multiple QGraphicsItem ( start, text, rectangle, polyline ) then how to override paint() method for all of them ? Can you help me in it ?

Comment: Then you need to inherit from and override the `paint` member for each of the `QGraphicsItem` types you use.  Sorry but this is the last comment I'll make here.

Comment: After all the efforts, now I am understanding what you were suggesting me. Like use Compostion instead of Inheritance, inherit `paint` method for every `QGraphicsItem`. I did everything. But while code reviewing, I was asked questions about `paint()`.  I tried to explain but may be I could not convey my thoughts. So can you little bit explain me about `paint()` logic you have used ? Means, how this `paint()` method knows on which co ordinates , I want to re paint ?  Is this `paint()` putting QGraphicsItem into `scene` again ?  ( my senior is mainly focusing on this )