# How to override virtual paint method?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am trying to change Qt's default selection nature by overriding virtual paint() method. But paint() method is not getting called. Mouse press and mouse release events are working properly but paint() is not getting called.

ellipse.h

```
    class ellipse : public QGraphicsView
{

public:

   ellipse();

   void paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
   QRectF boundingRect() const;
   bool pressed;

signals:
protected:
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
   void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
};
```

widget.h

```
    #include "ellipse.h"
    
    QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
    namespace Ui { class Widget; }
    QT_END_NAMESPACE
    
    class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    ellipse* ell;

};
```

ellipse.cpp

```
    ellipse::ellipse()
{
    pressed = false;
}
 void ellipse :: paint (QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
 {
     qDebug()<<"Inside paint ";
        if(pressed)
        {
            qDebug()<<"pressed ";
            QPainterPath path;
            path.addEllipse(2,2,220,220);
            painter->save();
            painter->setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
            painter->setPen(QPen(option->palette.windowText(), 0, Qt::DashLine));
            painter->drawPath(path);
            painter->restore();
        }
        else
            qDebug()<<"not selected ";
 }

 QRectF ellipse::boundingRect() const
 {

 }

 void ellipse::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
     qDebug()<<"mouse pressed ";
     pressed = true;
     update();
     QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
 }

 void ellipse::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
 {
     qDebug()<<"mouse released ";
     pressed = false;
     update();
     QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
 }
```

widget.cpp

```
 Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

   scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

    ell = new ellipse();
    ell->setScene(scene);

    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse1 = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();
    ellipse1 = scene->addEllipse(2,2,220,220);

    ellipse1->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);

    scene->addItem(ellipse1);
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(ell);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

How to solve this issue ? Can anyone help me ?

Comment: `QGraphicsItem` is not a `QObject`.  Remove `Q_OBJECT` from `ellipse`.

Comment: @RA.  Thanks. I removed QObject. Now there is no error. But paint() method is not getting called.

Comment: @RA. I applied some logs and found that, mousePressEvent is not occuring.

Comment: You never use your `ellipse` class.  You create a new `QGraphicsEllipseItem` with `QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse1 = new QGraphicsEllipseItem();`.  That memory is then leaked by the next line `ellipse1 = scene->addEllipse(2,2,220,220);` which tells the scene to create and add a `QGraphicsEllipseItem`.  That same item is then re-added to the scene with `scene->addItem(ellipse1);`.  The answer to your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977185/how-to-change-qts-default-selection-behavior) included a full example.  Did you try it?

Comment: @G.M. I tried to implement what you have said in above comment and accordingly updated the code.  But still paint() is not getting called. Mouse press and mouse release events are called properly.

Comment: @tushar Before going any further, have you tried to compile and run the code in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70985230/6371123).  If not then please do so and let me know whether or not it demonstrates the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: @G.M. Yes, it is working.  I checked.